# Error with AsyncTask when wifi is disabled

Tags: android, rss, android-asynctask

i m parsing rss feed in my app and i have tried to use a progress bar while loading the rss.This is my first time using AsyncTask.when i m pressing the button for the rss, the dialog appears and it stops when the rss load.So, its working..But,i checked from my logcat that when the wifi is turned off,i m getting the following error:

```
06-22 19:43:16.744: ERROR/OSFP.News(2316): java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.ConnectException: feeds.feedburner.com/209.85.146.118:80 - Network is unreachable
06-22 19:43:16.744: ERROR/OSFP.News(2316): java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.ConnectException: feeds.feedburner.com/209.85.146.118:80 - Network is unreachable
06-22 19:43:16.744: ERROR/OSFP.News(2316):     at com.example.async.DomFeedParser.parse(DomFeedParser.java:54)
06-22 19:43:16.744: ERROR/OSFP.News(2316):     at com.example.async.nea.loadFeed(nea.java:62)
06-22 19:43:16.744: ERROR/OSFP.News(2316):     at com.example.async.nea.onCreate(nea.java:51)
06-22 19:43:16.744: ERROR/OSFP.News(2316):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
06-22 19:43:16.744: ERROR/OSFP.News(2316):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
06-22 19:43:16.744: ERROR/OSFP.News(2316):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
06-22 19:43:16.744: ERROR/OSFP.News(2316):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
06-22 19:43:16.744: ERROR/OSFP.News(2316):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
06-22 19:43:16.744: ERROR/OSFP.News(2316):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-22 19:43:16.744: ERROR/OSFP.News(2316):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
06-22 19:43:16.744: ERROR/OSFP.News(2316):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
06-22 19:43:16.744: ERROR/OSFP.News(2316):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-22 19:43:16.744: ERROR/OSFP.News(2316):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
06-22 19:43:16.744: ERROR/OSFP.News(2316):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842)
06-22 19:43:16.744: ERROR/OSFP.News(2316):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
06-22 19:43:16.744: ERROR/OSFP.News(2316):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-22 19:43:16.744: ERROR/OSFP.News(2316): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.ConnectException: feeds.feedburner.com/209.85.146.118:80 - Network is unreachable
06-22 19:43:16.744: ERROR/OSFP.News(2316):     at com.example.async.BaseFeedParser.getInputStream(BaseFeedParser.java:32)
06-22 19:43:16.744: ERROR/OSFP.News(2316):     at com.example.async.DomFeedParser.parse(DomFeedParser.java:26)
06-22 19:43:16.744: ERROR/OSFP.News(2316):     ... 15 more
06-22 19:43:16.744: ERROR/OSFP.News(2316): Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: feeds.feedburner.com/209.85.146.118:80 - Network is unreachable
06-22 19:43:16.744: ERROR/OSFP.News(2316):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:207)
06-22 19:43:16.744: ERROR/OSFP.News(2316):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:437)
06-22 19:43:16.744: ERROR/OSFP.News(2316):     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:1002)
06-22 19:43:16.744: ERROR/OSFP.News(2316):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:75)
06-22 19:43:16.744: ERROR/OSFP.News(2316):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:48)
06-22 19:43:16.744: ERROR/OSFP.News(2316):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:322)
06-22 19:43:16.744: ERROR/OSFP.News(2316):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:89)
06-22 19:43:16.744: ERROR/OSFP.News(2316):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getHttpConnection(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:285)
06-22 19:43:16.744: ERROR/OSFP.News(2316):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.makeConnection(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:267)
06-22 19:43:16.744: ERROR/OSFP.News(2316):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.retrieveResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:1018)
06-22 19:43:16.744: ERROR/OSFP.News(2316):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:512)
06-22 19:43:16.744: ERROR/OSFP.News(2316):     at com.example.async.BaseFeedParser.getInputStream(BaseFeedParser.java:30)
06-22 19:43:16.744: ERROR/OSFP.News(2316):     ... 16 more
```

in my news activity i have used that for the turned off wifi:

```
catch (Throwable t){
            Log.e("OSFP.News",t.getMessage(),t);

            Toast.makeText(nea.this, "Please enable your wifi",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();
        }
```

Also,my asyncTask is used when i m pressing the button to start loading the news in my main activity:

```
nea = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nea);
        nea.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    new BackgroundAsyncTask().execute();
                    nea.setClickable(false);
                }});


//.......
public class BackgroundAsyncTask extends
       AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void> {
          private ProgressDialog dialog;
        int myProgress;

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            nea.setClickable(true);
             dialog.dismiss();

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
              dialog = ProgressDialog.show(main.this, "", "Loading. Please wait...", true);
            myProgress = 0;
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent newActivity111 = new Intent(main.this, nea.class);     
            startActivity(newActivity111);
            return null;
        }



    }
```

also,in my DomFeedParser class, i have that exception:

```
catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
```

Comment: An expected exception is caught and logged - what is the problem?

Comment: so that error in my logcat is no problem?

Comment: See mibollma's answer below.  Throwing the RuntimeException is not the way to go - do something about the error (like showing a Toast popup with an error message).

Comment: is it right the way i m using asyncTask?>

Comment: @haphazard i have tried to use a toast in the catch but eclipse says that its not used with DomFeedParser

Comment: The method makeText(Context, CharSequence, int) in the type Toast is not applicable for the arguments (DomFeedParser, String, int)

Comment: You can do it in the onPostExecute().  Pass the application context to the AsyncTask before you start it - you can pop the toast if you find that you have received the error.

Answer (score 1):

Don't catch the Exception class

```
catch (Exception e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
```

Instead you should handle the connection error gracefully

Look here to see how to do it right: http://source.android.com/source/code-style.html

Comment: @milbollma what do you suggest me to use herE?

Comment: What about catching the IOError you probably get when you can't connect and return an error code to onPostExecute

Comment: i have tried     catch (IOException d) {Log.d("OSFP.News",d.getMessage(),d);       but i m getting Unhandled exception type ParserConfigurationException

Comment: you have to catch both... IOException and ParserConfigurationException. For the second one you may throw RuntimeException for now but not for the first one.